# Search queries don't seem to work?

Tags: search, query

I have a problem with search queries. Anytime you put additional queries, like:

> mywebsite.com/?s=wordpress&post_type=page
>
> mywebsite.com/?s=wordpress&post_type=page,post
>
> mywebsite.net/?s=wordpress&cat=1
>
> mywebsite.net/?s=wordpress&post_type=post&tag=genesis-post
>
> mywebsite.net/?s=wordpress&post_type=post&tag=thesis-post

it should do a search in the specific scope (post type, category, tag).

In my case, it doesn't seem to work no matter what I put as an additional parameter, it will display all results containing the word I'm searching for.

In my post types, I have `query_var` set to `true` so in theory, it should work.

My search.php loop looks like this

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="post">

        <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : ?>
        <p class="category"><?php the_category(' '); ?></p>
        <?php else : ?>
        <p class="category">Resource</p>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 

    </div><!-- /post -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Using a hidden input in my searchform.php doesn't work either,

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"  class="search">
    <input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="myposttype" />
</form>
```

it still searches normal posts, not only within myposttype CPT.

Any idea why the search queries wouldn't work? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that passing `post_type` doesn't restrict searches to that type, but just *adds* that type to the array it already searches.

What you can do to build complex search queries is hook `pre_get_posts` and do a little query manipulation.

For a simple example, first I add my own query var to pass to WordPress's array of known query vars:

```
function wpa53029_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'my_type';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa53029_query_vars' );
```

Then set up the form to pass a post type, like:

> mywebsite.com/?s=wordpress&my_type=page
>
> mywebsite.com/?s=wordpress&my_type=page,mycustomtype

Then add some code to intercept that query var before the database is queried, and set post type:

```
function wpa53029_pre_get_posts( $query ){
    if( isset( $query->query_vars['my_type'] ) ){
        $types = explode( ',', $query->query_vars['my_type'] );
        $query->set( 'post_type', $types );
    }

    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa53029_pre_get_posts' );
```

For debugging, print out the contents of the query object in your `search.php` template to see how everything is being set, and the actual SQL query WordPress generates to query the database. WordPress uses `$wp_query` as the global variable which holds the main query:

```
<pre>
    <?php print_r( $wp_query ); ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: should this work with more than one post type sent to the query? Search for keyword (mysite.com/?s=keyword) returns two posts from two different post types. When I search for that keyword and one of the post types (mysite.com/?s=keyword&my_type=typeone) it returns the correct post (and printing the $wp_query displays all information about it). However, if i search for both post types (mysite.com/?s=keyword&my_type=typeone,typetwo) it returns nothing, no posts and nothing in $wp_query. Any ideas?

Comment: @Justine - it only accepts a single type, I've updated the `wpa53029_pre_get_posts` function above so you can now pass a comma-separated list of types and it will convert them to an array for the query.

Comment: this helped passing a list of types to the query, however it started showing pages in my search results.. (I had a filter above that to only include 'post' and my custom post types: `$query->set('post_type', array('post', 'typeone', 'typetwo', 'typethree'));` Any reason why it suddenly started ignoring this filter? It's also set on `pre_get_posts` and worked with your previous snippet (with quering just one post type).

Comment: any chance for last bit of help on this one? I'd be very grateful, can't figure this out :)

Comment: It also started causing a problem with custom menus, as described here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53144/custom-search-filter-made-menu-disappear/53147#comment68383_53147

Comment: ...and with any custom query I have on other pages, like `query_posts('post_type=organization')` - displays normal posts instead of what's in the `query_posts`

Comment: @Justine - see my comment at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53144/custom-search-filter-causes-menu-and-query-posts-problems/53147#53147 it's the name of your query var that's the issue, make it something unique.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, so it might not work quite like I think it will, but try this:

```
$post_type = $_GET['post_type'];

global $query_string
query_posts( $query_string . '&post_type=' . $post_type );

// loop here
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will help me. I'm trying to build a more advanced search form with checkboxes for categories, post types and tags and need the URL queries to work properly. I just can't figure out why they don't.

Comment: Didn't help; http://mysite.com/?s=lorem&post_type=myposttype still returns all post types as result. Unrelated, but it seems ?cat and ?tag suddenly started to work, so my only problem is post type now...

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help.