# Custom search filter causes menu and query_posts problems

Tags: menus, query-posts, filters, search, pre-get-posts

I'm using a custom search filter (using my custom query var `type`), like so:

```
function fteh_pre_get_posts( $query ){
    if( isset( $query->query_vars['type'] ) )
        $types = explode( ',', $query->query_vars['type'] );
        $query->set( 'post_type', $types );

    return $query;
}

if ( ! is_admin() ) {
     add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'fteh_pre_get_posts' );
}
```

I noticed this causes a registered custom menu to disappear.

Without the `!is_admin()` it also confused the menu builder (it showed some posts instead of all my pages in Pages section). Adding the condition helped with that, but I can't figure out how to bring back my menu.

It's properly registered and called, build and saved in proper theme location and worked before adding that filter. Now it just uses the `fallback_cb` (in my case the default `wp_page_menu`) instead of my custom menu.

As soon as I remove that action from `pre_get_posts`, everyting is back to normal.

I don't see how `pre_get_posts` hook is related to the custom menus - does anyone know why it would cause such a weird behavior?

**UPDATE:**

I now discovered another problem caused specifically by the snippet above - all my custom queries on pages (simple stuff like `query_posts('post_type=organization')`) stopped working and display normal posts instead of custom post types set up in `query_posts`.

Comment: "*I don't see how `pre_get_posts` hook is related to the custom menus*" - that's because nav menu items are *posts*, and are *queried* as *posts*. Also: don't **ever** use `query_posts()`. Use `WP_Query()` instead for custom query loops, or use `pre_get_posts` to modify the main query.

Answer (score 13):

Use [`is_main_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query) to modify only the main query so menu will stay not affected.

**Try This:**

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'fteh_pre_get_posts' );

    function fteh_pre_get_posts( $query ){
        if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && isset( $query->query_vars['type'] ) )
            $types = explode( ',', $query->query_vars['type'] );
            $query->set( 'post_type', $types );

        return $query;
    }
```

Comment: Didn't work - no change at all, menu is still gone/using fallback and removing `is_admin` condition messes up menu builder (Appearance->Menus - Pages section/widget)

Comment: wordpress menus are Custom Post Type. type name is `nav_menu_item`. You might want to exclude that post type from `$types`. Though i am not sure what is you trying to do with the code.

Comment: The code is a part of a bigger search filtering plugin/code but only this part causes problems. `$types` definitely doesn't include `nav_menu_item`

Comment: @Justine - try using a query var less generic than `type`, that's a reserved word in WordPress and may be causing a conflict.

Comment: @Milo - changed the query var to `myprefix_type`, nothing changed :(

Comment: @Milo - This is how all search filtering snippets look in my functions.php right now - http://pastebin.com/reNpXK4P

Comment: @Justine - your code works for me in a default install + twentyeleven theme, i'm not sure where the issue is.

Comment: @Milo - would you be willing to look at my install/theme? How could I contact you to send you an URL privately?

Comment: Did you end up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little late to the party but this is what I did to fix my issue with the menu disappearing when I was viewing custom posts by category.  I am using default post categories and not custom taxonomies.

```
public function include_custom_post_search( $query ) {
        if( ! is_admin() ) {

            if( is_category() && 'nav_menu_item' !== $query->get('post_type') )
                $query->set( 'post_type', 'custom_post_place_slug' );
        }
    }

    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'include_custom_post_search' );
```